# How to get each last modified file timestamp in a folder which is older than 2 hours using java

Tags: java

How to get timestamp for each last modified file in a folder which is older than 2 hours using java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [java.io.File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html) class contains all you need:

Get all the files in a directory using [listFiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#listFiles()).
Loop over the returned files, and use [lastModified()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#lastModified()) to retrieve the timestamp.

The timestamp is measured in milliseconds since the epoch (00:00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970). So you can check if

```
System.currentTimeMillis() - file.lastModified() > 2 * 3600 * 1000
```